# Active Directory Sites and Services - can subnets affect the applicability of GPOs?

Tags: active-directory

This maybe a dump question. But I have a strange situation here. Two of my servers (Windows Server 2012 R2) do not apply any GPO that are linked to the respective OUs. Gpresult /H simply returns an empty result set.

Now i have realized that a defined subnet contains a wrong mask. To clarify:

- Server IP address: 192.168.1.10 / 255.255.255.0 / 24
- Subnet defined in ADSS: 192.168.1.0 / 255.255.254.0 / 23

I suspect that this is just a typo someone made. Can this affect the application of GPOs?

Comment: Well, first of all, you need to determine what the proper subnet is.  Is it a 23 bit or a 24 bit subnet?  Then you need to figure out why the Servers aren't getting any GPOs applied, which *could* be related to the subnet confusion, but probably isn't.  In any event, resolve the subnet confusion first, then you'll know if the problem is related to that or not.

Comment: the correct subnet mask is /24. But maybe there is another subnet 192.168.0.0 i am not aware of

Comment: That's not going to be your problem, then, since `192.168.1.0/24` fits inside the defined site (`192.168.1.0/23`) in ADSS.  Gonna have to look elsewhere - `rsop.msc`, `gpresult /z`, filtering settings on the GPOs, etc.

Comment: okay, but could it (in theory) affect the applicability?

Comment: Your subnets (and their relation to your sites) will affect what domain controllers clients look to for authentication and the application of Group Policy but they shouldn't have an affect on whether or not an OU linked GPO is applied or not. They would be affected by Site linked GPO's, but not OU linked GPO's. The order of GPO application is: LSDOU - Local, Site, Domain, OU. So an incorrect subnet may affect a Site linked GPO but shouldn't affect an OU linked GPO.